# Javascript event.target.value returning different value in firefox than in Chorme/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm creating a checkout system as a school project in PHP usign jquery ajax and i'm having a strange issue with values returned from event.target in javascript. Here is the HTML and JS.

HTML:

```
<td>
    <button class='checkout-remove-btn' value='102' onclick='removeProduct(event)'>
        <span class='table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
    </button>
</td>
```

JS: (for debugging will be replaced with ajax post)

```
function removeProduct(event) {
    alert(event.target.value + " " + event.target.parentElement.value);
}
```

The issue is that the returns are different in Firefox and Chrome/IE.

```
Firefox:
target.value = 102
target.parentElement.value = undefined

Chrome:
target.value = undefined
target.parentElement.value = 102
```

I don't know why they are being handled differently, is there a way to correctly get the value 102?

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking on the `span` in both cases? The behaviour is consistent with the event bubbling up from the `span` in Chrome and clicking the `button` directly in Firefox

Comment: I don't see any jQuery here, one of jQuery strengths is hiding browser differences...  You might try it 'the jQuery way'

Comment: you are right @RoryMcCrossan in Firefox it clicks the button and in chrome/IE the span, any idea why?

Comment: @JohnHascall sorry the i was using jquery for the ajax but removed it to insert the alert debug. What would be the jquery way of handling the event value?

Comment: Sorry not to answer sooner -- on a plane all day -- anyway looks like you got a great answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the jQuery way of handling the event value?

You would attach the event handler using `on()` or `click()` and then use the `this` keyword to reference the clicked element, like this:

```js
$('.checkout-remove-btn').click(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="checkout-remove-btn" value="102">
  <span class="table-remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>
```

Attaching the event in this manner removes the ambiguity about which element raised the event as `this` will always refer to the element in your selector.

Comment: thanks a lot very new to jquery/javascript, this method is solid :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. For reference you should avoid the `on*` event attributes where at all possible. They're considered very outdated now.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a browser issue, but more likely the result of where you click on the button.

If you click on the `span`, `event.target` will be the span element, because the click event bubbles up the DOM. If you click on the `button`, but outside the `span`, then `event.target` will be the button, which has a value.

There are many ways you could work out which element has been clicked on, this one relies on the classes of the elements:

```
function removeProduct(event) {
    if(event.target.classList.contains('glyphicon') {
        alert(event.target.parentElement.value);
    } else {
        alert(event.target.value);
    }
}
```